# it keeps navigating me to top of page when clicking on a button

Tags: html, css

Below is a piece of code where it styles a checkbox to make it look like a button, problem I am having though is how come when I click on the checkbox button that it keeps navigating me to the top top of the page?

HTML/PHP:

```
echo '<div id="ck-button"><label><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
```

CSS:

```
#ck-button {
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#ck-button:hover {
    background:green;
}

#ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript on the page or any links around the element?

Comment: I don't think that it's anything to do with the code you have posted. The probblem must be located elsewhere on the page in some other code that is affecting the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to the `#ck-button` selector.

```
#ck-button {
    margin:8px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Here's a working example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/asiqid/1/). (scroll down to see the button)